# m2eclipse how make a webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, maven, m2eclipse

I select New Project Wizard and choose Maven Project from the list. In Archetype selection panel select maven-archetype-webapp. Make the project, but i dont see to deploy on tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the Maven integration for WTP plugin (a.k.a m2eclipse-wtp). It's available from the m2eclipse Update Site hosted by JBoss: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/

Once you've installed it, right click on your project > Maven > Update Project configuration.
The m2eclipse-wtp plugin will take care of configuring the WTP settings for your project from the maven-war-plugin configuration from your pom.xml.

Once configured, you should have access to the "Run > Run on server" menu

Comment: It worked for me as well. Thanks. There is li'l issue here. I can't see src/main/java, src/test/java and src/test/resource?

Comment: Because the archetype didn't create these folders (it's not a m2e issue). You need to manually create these folders then run "Maven > Update Project Configuration" so they can be added to the Eclipse classpath.

Answer (score 3):

> right click > run > run on server > add your preferred server and run

Comment: Java Applet Java Application Junit test and other meven but not run in server.

Comment: If you can enable maven dependency> right click > maven >enable maven dependecy

Answer (score 0):

Do a maven-package, navigate to http://localhost:8080/manager and do a war upload.